# monospaced font for coding with splitted underlines

Tags: python, fonts, sublimetext2

Are there any monospaced fonts with separate underlines, like this:

[image]

with support of Cyrillic script? Consolas' underlines are not separate and Adobe Source Code Pro doesn't support Cyrillic script right now. 
Or maybe can I enable Adobe Source Code Pro for Latin script and Consolas for Cyrillic script in sublime text 2?
I need it for coding in python in sublime text 2.

Comment: Added tag [sublimetext2]. I think the answer may involve knowing how the [Sublime Text 2 editor](http://www.sublimetext.com) handles fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Monofur](http://www.dafont.com/monofur.font). It has the separate underscores, and has Cyrillic glyphs.

Comment: Some digits and cyrillic letters look odd, but it can be a solution if there is no another one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try Inconsolata - not only it is one on of the popular and fast growing fonts around, it has what you're asking for and it is free.
If you're on Ubuntu, you can even install simply by:

> sudo apt-get install fonts-inconsolata

Enjoy!

Comment: Unfortunately Inconsolata doesn't have Cyrillic script, but [Inconsolata-LGC](https://github.com/MihailJP/Inconsolata-LGC/downloads) has! Many thanks!